# jquery after() method

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function:

```
$(".slider").click(function () {

    $(this).after('<span class="slider">click me again</span>');

 });

//before first click   
<span class="slider">first click</span>

//after first click
<span class="slider">first click</span>
<span class="slider">click me again</span>
```

When I click on "click me again", function does not fire.

I tried, live and on and a few other ways, but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In *what way* did you 'try `live()`, `on()` and a few other ways'? If we don't know what you did, we don't know what you did wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7) to bind the event:

```
$(document).on("click", ".slider", function () {
    ...
```

[`.click( ... )`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is short for [`.bind('click', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), which only binds the event to the elements which exist at that time. Elements which are added later do not receive this event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Using the live() method works fine, actually:

```
$(".slider").live('click',function () {
    $(this).after('<span class="slider">click me again</span>');
});
```

Make sure do embed this code in your $(document).ready() handler.

Answer (score 0):

You say you used `on()`, so I'm led to believe you were using it incorrectly.

The syntax required for `on()` to work on dynamic elements is like such:

```
$(document).on("click", ".slider", function(){
    // click event fired
});
```

Notice that we're targeting the document and delegating the click event to all children with the class `slider`.

It is recommended to use as close a parent as possible for `on()`, because when you use `document`, events bubble up to the document level, which can lower performance and slow things down. So it's better to target the closest parent of the spans that exists when the page loads.

`live()` is also deprecated, so for versions of jQuery below 1.7, it is much more preferred and in fact recommended to use `delegate()`.

More on `on()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and more on `delegate()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).